# Delegate function is not firing-Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

Scenario:
I have a table view and a custom button cell. In controller of cell I have made a delegate to call a function of MainController.
Issue is my cell button action is firing but the delete function not.

CustomCell Controller:

```
import UIKit

protocol CustChatButtonDelegate: class {
    func chatActionClick(cell: CustButtonCell)
}
class CustButtonCell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegete:CustChatButtonDelegate?
     @IBOutlet weak var btnChat: UIButton!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
//        self.delegete=nil
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    @IBAction func btnChatActionClick(_ sender: Any) {
        print("btn click")
        self.delegete?.chatActionClick(cell: self)
    }

}
```

MainController:

```
import UIKit

class ChatController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ChatButtonDelegate,CustChatButtonDelegate {

func chatActionClick(cell: CustButtonCell) {
        print("btnClicked")
    }

}
```

Comment: add `cell.delegate = self` where you creating the cell

Comment: Have you set the delegate property of the CustButtonCell? Also, you might want to declare the delegate as `weak` because you would otherwise have a reference cycle.

Comment: where is your `<myCustomsCellInstance>.delegate = self` (or something similar) in your code? or in other words, where did you assign a value to the `delegate` var?

Comment: cell.delegate = self worked for me thanks alot  ^_^ .Please add your comment as separate answer.

Answer (score 8):

This is a fairly common issue.

Simply add `cell.delegate = self` where you are creating the cell, for example in `cellForRowAt`.

Also make your delegate property `weak`.

Answer (score 0):

Delegating object should maintain a **weak** reference to its delegate.

```
weak var delegete: CustChatButtonDelegate?
```

Please note that **strong** is applied on object references by default.